# redirectTo for IndexRoute

Tags: ember.js

I'm having a problem with the following not working. I'm taking this pretty much directly from the Tom Dale video but it isn't redirecting - it just sits on that url. Is there some syntax wrong? Or possibly other positining I met be missing?

```
App.IndexRoute=Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function(){
    this.transitionTo('upcomingevents');    
  } 
});
```

Sorry for posting a simple question but just not sure what's wrong here. Any ideas?

Comment: Without much more context, it's difficult to tell you what's wrong. Could you post at least your routing map ? A jsbin/jsfiddle of your example will be even better. For now, the only idea I have is that the  `upcomingevents` route does not exist.

Comment: did you get possible answer for this??? am facing same issue with rc6..i think there is no redirection to Index route if we are not providing same....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that issue is with Ember.JS only. If we are not giving about specific route on application load, it should redirect to Index route which was working fine before. There is some change in condition which created this problem. if i change [this condition(follow the link)](https://gist.github.com/thecodejack/5866860#file-ember-rc6-js-L25178) from

```
if (url === "" || url === "/" || parts[parts.length-1] === "index") { this.explicitIndex = true; }
```

to

```
if (url === "" || url === "/") { this.explicitIndex = true; }
```

it now works fine with out any issue. i hope they know this issue and correct it.

Answer (score 2):

> Is there some syntax wrong? Or possibly other positining I met be missing?

It could be any number of things. Try setting LOG_TRANSITIONS on your application so that you can see console output as ember changes routes. That might give a better indication of what is going wrong.

```
App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true
});
```

If that doesn't help, try making a jsFiddle that demonstrates the problem. You can use [this one](http://jsfiddle.net/mgrassotti/qzqFa/) to start, it's based on the Tom Dale video and includes a working index redirect.

Comment: a good starting point. stopped using Ember because other things came up